# Approach to removing extra space at beginning of RSS file?

Tags: 7, theming, feeds

I ran the RSS xml file through W3C's RSS validator. The [results](http://validator.w3.org/feed/check.cgi?url=http://complicatedmelody.com/rss.xml) say:

```
line 2, column 0: XML parsing error: <unknown>:2:0: XML or text declaration not at start of entity
```

I'm not sure how to approach this one. I searched on drupal.org and found these:

- [RSS Problem](http://drupal.org/node/521118)
- [XML Parsing Error: XML or text declaration not at the start of entity .... solution.](http://drupal.org/node/875200)

Based on the 2nd link, I tried placing an echo in the current template.php being used and the output appeared **after** the space right before the XML tag. That means the extra line in the RSS XML was placed there **before** the theming was invoked, right? Where should I look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems all of the core and contrib modules were solid. It was the premium theme I used. The new line may not have been in template.php but it was in another file invoked from inside template.php.

My approach:
In a local development environment, I added an echo statement in suspected areas. When I added echo at the bottom of the template.php, the output appeared as described in the question **but** when I placed the echo at the start of the template.php, the echo output appeared **before** the newline so I tracked down inside template.php what functions or other php files it was calling and soon, I found the dependency php file that had extra lines and fixed it.

This might differ in your case though.

Answer (score 3):

Someone left a space at the beginning of a module.

```
[space]<?php
```

You can either try to find that bit of code with some tool or command OR put this in includes/bootstrap.inc at line 1112:

```
echo $filename;
```

The line number could change subject to updates to Drupal 7 so make sure it is inside the drupal_load function:

```
if ($filename) {
    echo $filename;  //this is your included line
    include_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/' . $filename;
    $files[$type][$name] = TRUE;
```

The result will be a long list of the modules being loaded in source code of the page.  The space will be right after the module with the problem.

Answer (score 2):

As JAmatulli said its mostly because someone left a space at very beginning  in template or module or inc file

Here is another way of using grep to find the culprit. Mostly it is module file so...

```
grep -R -H '^  <?php' modules/**/*.module
```

This will check all module files withing your module folder ( i am a step back in my sites/all folder in my linux terminal to find culprit.)
If you find two spaces leave two space between ^ and

If you just get the filename you can find its path via

```
locate -br 'culprit.module'
```

After correcting clear cache. :)

Improvising: `grep -R -H '^ *<?php' modules/**/*.module`
Check for one or more spaces.

For windows: `findstr "^ *<?php" *.module`
Current position inside modules directory, will check for all .module file withing modules and its sub directory.

Comment: This worked for me:  `grep -R -H --include=*.module '^ <?php'`

Answer (score 1):

Echo gives a long list of module names and finding a space is difficult. Instead I check for the space in the file name only.

```
if ($filename) {
  if (strrpos($filename, " ")) {
      echo $filename;
  }
  include_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/' . $filename;
  $files[$type][$name] = TRUE;
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had a leading space in my settings.php file. So the file was included before the first call of drupal_load() in bootstrap.inc.

Showing all included files before the first include called by drupal_load() gave me good insights of where to look at. I placed this code at the same place as in the answers above.

```
  if(!isset($GLOBALS['show_once'])){
      echo '<pre>'.print_r(get_included_files(), true).'</pre>';
      $GLOBALS['show_once'] = 5;
  }
```

To check every included file for a space or new line character near to php-tags:

```
$file_arr = get_included_files();

foreach ($file_arr as $file){

    if(preg_match('/(\s<\?php)|(\?>\s)/mi', file_get_contents($file)) > 0)
          echo 'The file '.$file.' contains spaces or new lines near the php-tags.<br>';

}
```