# Extra space at beginning of downloaded image

Tags: media

I'm using custom code to download images, as I need to check permissions and keep a trace of each download (inter alia).

Here's how I decided to go:

- Simple link, triggering an AJAX call of my download page
- As it's an AJAX called page, `html--ajax.tpl.php` is used
- Same for `page--ajax.tpl.php`
- My final file force the image download

...and the content of the 3 related files:

**html--ajax.tpl.php**:

```
<?php print $page; ?>
```

**page--ajax.tpl.php**:

```
<?php print render($page['content']); ?>
```

**download.ajax.php**:

```
<?php

// ...extra code to populate $path and $filename

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream'); 
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($path));
readfile($path);
exit;
```

> **My problem is that I've an extra space in my downloaded image bytes**

The downloaded image is corrupted, so I decided to compare its bytes with the original image with `xxd`, and here's the result where you can see an extra `20` byte at the very beginning:

```
00000000: 20ff d8ff e000 104a 4649 4600 0101 0000   ......JFIF.....
00000010: 0100 0100 00ff fe00 3b43 5245 4154 4f52  ........;CREATOR
00000020: 3a20 6764 2d6a 7065 6720 7631 2e30 2028  : gd-jpeg v1.0 (
00000030: 7573 696e 6720 494a 4720 4a50 4547 2076  using IJG JPEG v
00000040: 3632 292c 2071 7561 6c69 7479 203d 2037  62), quality = 7
00000050: 300a ffdb 0043 000a 0707 0807 060a 0808  0....C..........
00000060: 080b 0a0a 0b0e 1810 0e0d 0d0e 1d15 1611  ................
00000070: 1823 1f25 2422 1f22 2126 2b37 2f26 2934  .#.%$"."!&+7/&)4
00000080: 2921 2230 4131 3439 3b3e 3e3e 252e 4449  )!"0A149;>>>%.DI
00000090: 433c 4837 3d3e 3bff db00 4301 0a0b 0b0e  C<H7=>;...C.....
```

I used the same approach as the one described in [this post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/60509/approach-to-removing-extra-space-at-beginning-of-rss-file) to find the origin the the space. The better I could have is to determine that the space appears in `page--ajax.tpl.php` :

```
00000000: 5020 44ff d8ff e000 104a 4649 4600 0101  P D......JFIF...
```

**P** is printed before the `render()`, in `page--ajax.tpl.php`, and **D** before my `readfile()`.

Any ideas to helps me to find the origin of this space?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Vinodkumar's answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/163642/33690) didn't solved my issue, but it pointed me in the right direction.

I still haven't found the extra space, but as Drupal already used `ob_start()` in `bootstrap.inc`, I can now call `ob_clean()` to ensure no extra characters are shown:

```
<?php

// ...extra code to populate $path and $filename

ob_clean();
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream'); 
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($path));
readfile($path);
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove extra space in the file download.ajax.php at the top. If that didn't work then try to call ob_start() function at the start of the file and check it. It will work.